# Would an USB external graphic card disable the on-board graphic card?

Tags: usb, display, port, vga

I am trying to connect my Dell Slim Studio 540S with 3 monitors.

Would an USB external graphic card like this [Sewell USB to Display (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WjqA8yRIMk) disable the on-board graphic card in the Dell Slim Studio 540S desktop computer?

Answer (score 0):

it didn't for us.  We have several PCs hosting 4-6 monitors we use for, well, monitoring.  The internal card runs 2 and two externals run the others.

Comment: I want to point out that the internal video card in my Dell Slim Studio 540S is ONBOARD, that is integrated with the motherboard. Would the ONBOARD graphic card be disabled when an external USB graphic card runs?

Comment: It did not for our Dell Optiplex PCs with onboard video.